# How to redirect force https with version and SEO friendly URL using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /version_X
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|files|icon|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

# Added for redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I am using Codeigniter. My .htaccess is in `project_root/version_X` directory. so my project root is `project_root` and code is in `version_X`.

My project URL is `http://subdomain.domain.com/version_X/login`. but when i am using the above script it is redirected to `https://subdomain.domain.com/version_X/index.php?/login` instead of `https://subdomain.domain.com/version_X/login`.

I am using the proxy subdomain (aws).

So how to redirect force https with version and SEO friendly using .htaccess?

Comment: Move `R=301` rule to top and retest.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, it is working now after moving this line to top, thank you very much.